# I have a string list in a panda dataframe I need to conditionally change the string 'american' to 'english'

Tags: pandas, list, element

I would like to change the element 'american' to 'english'.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Language':[['cantonese', 'japanese', 
                 'mandarin','american'],['mand. mandarin''english'], 
                 ['american', 'mandarin','cantonese']]})

df 
                                Language
0   [cantonese, japanese, mandarin, american]
1   [mandarin, english]
2   [american, mandarin, cantonese]
```

Wanted:

```
                                      Language
0   [cantonese, japanese, mandarin, english]
1   [mandarin, english]
2   [english, mandarin, cantonese]
```

Answer (score 0):

For Pandas 0.25+, you can use `epxlode`:

```
df['Language'] = (df['Language'].explode()
                     .replace('american','english')
                     .groupby(level=0).agg(list)
                 )
```

In general, you can also use list comprehension:

```
df['Language'] = [['english' if y=='american' else y for y in x] 
                   for x in df['Language'] ]
```

Output:

```
                                   Language
0  [cantonese, japanese, mandarin, english]
1                       [mandarin, english]
2            [english, mandarin, cantonese]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great.